# Change color of Text box on click in ASP.NET web form

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having trouble getting my `TextBox` to change color when clicked, from red to black. I need to change my `if/else` I believe.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        messageTextBox1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        if(messageTextBox1.Clicked == true)
        {
            ForeColor = Color.Red; 
        }
        else
        {
            ForeColor = Color.Black;``
        }
    }

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        messageTextBox1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Please advise.

Comment: I see no `for` loop in this code.

Comment: Do you want to change textBox color when checkBox was checked/unchecked?

Comment: Why do you have `checkBox1_CheckedChanged` and `checkBox1_CheckedChanged_1`? Either way, just do `messageTextBox1.ForeColor = (checkBox1.Checked) ? Color.Red : Color.Black;` in your `CheckedChanged` event. You're just calling `ForeColor`, without specifying an object before it, so I believe it should be changing the `ForeColor` of your form- not the textbox.

Comment: Sorry I meant if statement,

Comment: Can you show us the code for the checkbox as well?

Comment: @DannyBurke Do you want the text to **only** change color when they click the text AND your checkbox is checked?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your `CheckBox_CheckedChanged` event to this:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    messageTextBox1.ForeColor = checkBox1.Checked ? Color.Red : Color.Black;
}
```

The syntax on the right hand side of the `=` basically evaluates the expression directly to the left of `?`, like an `if` statement would, and then assigns the value directly to the left of the `:` if the expression is true, or the value to the right of `:` if the expression is false.

More information:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx

I believe this is sometimes called a "ternary operator", but MSDN calls it a conditional operator.

Comment: Combine this with Grant Winney's suggestion from the comments and you've got a winner

Comment: Based on this code of OP (`if(messageTextBox1.Clicked == true)`) he probably wants when he clicked on the `TextBox` color should changes.

Comment: @user2946329 I think you might be right, but his post is a little unclear and the code is kind of conflicting. This was my best interpretation.